# bipartite d regular expender explicit construction

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching, expanders, bipartite-graph

I am looking for an explicit (and simple) construction of a d regular bi bipartite graph which is an expander. I searched the web and didn't find any sufficient answer.
The only explicit graph I did managed to find(and understand) was the margolis graph, but as far as I can understand this graph is not a bipartite (for example (0,0) has a self edge).

Please help me.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/ViolaWi2017_v2.pdf